# Nested foreach loop modifying the inner object when it's not supposed to

Tags: c#, foreach, nested

I have 2 foreach loops nested like so:

```
foreach (var item in temp)
{
    foreach (var merge in distrolist)
    {
        if(merge.Name.Equals(item.Name) && !merge.Projeid.Equals(item.Projeid))
        {
            item.Amount += merge.Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

this code, when executed, modifies the merge object's amount in the distrolist. I am quite confused as to why. Now, the interesting part is that the modified object is actually not the current merge object in the loop, rather than a previous object in the distrolist. Temp and distrolist are of the same generic type. I'm not sure what more to add, but if you want to see more details I can edit the question.

Comment: You will need to show the relevant parts of code here i.e. how is `distrolist` created and how is `temp` created, and the full type definitions of both. It's possible that the types are reference types and they refer to the same instance of the object

Comment: Very well, I will edit now

Comment: it is highly likely that both temp and distrlist contains same merge instances

Comment: Yes apparently they do. I will clean up the code a bit, thanks a lot

Comment: I think the question would be clearer if you provided sample data and explain what this should actually do. It seems your trying to do the following: for each item in temp you increase the item's `Amount` by the sum of the `Amount`s of all things in `distroList` that have the same name as the `item` but a _different_ `Projeid`. Is this intended? I have no idea what the business model is....

Comment: _"...modified object is [...] not the current merge object.."_ I actually don't see where you modify any merge object. You only modify `item.Amount`.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do. It's my secret proprietary in-house business model. The world is not ready for such eye-watering greatness. Yes I'm also modifying only the item's amount property, but the debugger says when the line is executed the previous merge's amount in the distrolist also gets modified.

Comment: then Matt.G.seems right that both lists contain the same references